# Select specific div class in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I get problems when I parse a specific `div`'s class.

```
<div class="box_3 box_3a">

    <div class="title_new_2"></div>

    <div class="list_indeks_2"></div>

</div>
```

I have tried to select `<div class="list_indeks_2"></div>` with jsoup as follows:

```
 links = doc.select(".list_indeks_2")
```

However, this code didn't work because the `div`'s class contains underscores (`_`). How does one handle an underscore (`_`) in the jsoup `select` method?

Comment: *"but this code didn't work because the div class has _ . how to handle _ in jsoup select?"* What makes you think the `_` is a problem? It's a perfectly valid CSS class name character.

Comment: i just predict the error because when i use class without _ my code running well but when i use class with _ my code cannot extract. do you have suggestion to extract <div class="list_indeks_2"></div> ?

Comment: Well, I just tried it, and your code works just fine. The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Try to access the element based on the attribute.

The snippet was tested with JSoup version 1.8.1.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(
        "<div class=\"box_3 box_3a\">\n"
        + "    <div class=\"title_new_2\">some title</div>\n"
        + "    <div class=\"list_indeks_2\">some index</div>\n"
        + "</div>");
Elements rows = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "list_indeks_2");
System.out.println("rows.size() = " + rows.size());
String index = "";
for (Element span : rows) {
    index = span.text();
}
System.out.println("index = " + index);
```

this produces as output

```
rows.size() = 1
index = some index
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. However, your code still cannot extract the class. i predict my problem in _ character because when i use class without _ my code running well. ` Elements links =  doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "list_indeks_2"); 
                    System.out.println(links.size());` i got links.size() still 0, the value should not 0 if my code running well.

Comment: @wiratama I have updated my snippet. I can't guess why your `links.size()` as in the snippet it returns `1`. Post your code which is failing so we could have a closer look.